# Counting unique characters in a string

Tags: java, character, unique, counting

So i have been trying to make a code that counts the number of words in a string which was pretty easy. I'm running into problems when im trying to make it count the number of unique characters in a string. The program compiles and runs  it doesn't display the number of Unique characters. Adding a System.out.println(countOfUniqueChars); below return doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
public class Uniquechar{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "Jag vet inte vad jag heter idag";
    String[] parts = s.split(" ");
    int wordcount = parts.length;
    System.out.println("The number of words is" + wordcount);

    countUniqueCharacters(s);
}

public static int countUniqueCharacters(String s) {
    String lowerCase = s.toLowerCase();
    char characters[] = lowerCase.toCharArray();
    int countOfUniqueChars = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        if (i != lowerCase.indexOf(characters[i])) {
            countOfUniqueChars--;
        }
    }
    return countOfUniqueChars;
}
```

Comment: Just try to put into `SET` it will accept only unique character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `System.out.println(countUniqueCharacters(s));` in the main method, to output the return value of your method. After a return, you cannot add more code. I did it for you and the output is `12`, so it seems to be that there is also something wrong with your algorithm.

```
    int uniqeCharsCount = countUniqueCharacters(s);
    System.out.println("The number of uniqe chars is " + uniqeCharsCount);
```

**Output: 12**

Your algorithm:

Actually you are checking every char, if this char is one more time in the string `before`. But you should also check if the char is anywhere in the string `after` the current index. You can fix it if you change your if condition to `if (i != lowerCase.indexOf(characters[i]) || i != lowerCase.lastIndexOf(characters[i]))`

**Output of the fixed version: 3** (n, h, r)

Comment: Well 12 is actually right. Maybe i was not clear with what i was trying to do but i was trying to count the number of Unique characters in the string, being: j a g v e t i n v d h r

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
s = s.replace(" ", ""); // If you don't want to count space
char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
Set<Character> uniqueChars = new HashSet<>();

for (char c : chars) {
   uniqueChars.add(c);
}

System.out.println(c.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just print the method call, it prints the result.

```
   System.out.println(countUniqueCharacters(s));
```

> Adding a System.out.println(countOfUniqueChars); below return doesn't work.

It won't work. Because the code after return statement is unreachable. Perhaps you can do it just before `return`.

```
System.out.println(countOfUniqueChars);
return countOfUniqueChars;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `Set` to retain only uniques, then count its size, instead of iterating:

```
public static int countUniqueCharacters(String s) {
    String lowerCase = s.toLowerCase();
    char characters[] = lowerCase.toCharArray();
    Set<Character> uniques = new HashSet<Character>();
    for (char c: characters) {
        uniques.add(c);
    }
    return uniques.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (i != lowerCase.indexOf(characters[i])) {
    countOfUniqueChars--;
}
```

This is wrong. Your lowerCase string is lowercase, so any uppercase letters in characters[i] will have an index of -1 in lowerCase (will be calculated as a non-unique character). You can fix this by using indexOf(lowerCase.charAt(i));

Answer (score 0):

A good way to count the number of characters would be eliminating repetitions. The ideia is get the first character, then find next occurrences and replace by nothing, once you do that you can count the unique characters.

```
public static int countUniqueCharacters(String s) {
    String lowerCase = s.toLowerCase();

    ///Get the first char of lowerCase
    String firstChar = lowerCase.substring(0,1);
    //Take off the first char
    String subS = lowerCase.substring(1);
    ///replace all chars equals to first char
    String replacedSubS = subS.replace(firstChar, "");

    /// Now, call method again to calculate size
    /// of the substring with first char
    // replaced by blank char
    return  1+countUniqueCharacters(replacedSubS);
}
```

This method worked for me, take a look. You may do that in two lines, but i thought it's better be detailed here.

Answer (score 0):

> Adding a `System.out.println(countOfUniqueChars);` below `return` doesn't work.

That is expected behavior because `return` means that flow of control will be returned from method to place where this method was invoked. This means that code after `return` will not be executed, so in situation like

```
return countOfUniqueChars;
System.out.println(countOfUniqueChars);
```

`System.out.println(countOfUniqueChars);` would be *dead code*.

You could try printing value before you return it like

```
System.out.println(countOfUniqueChars);
return countOfUniqueChars;
```

or simply print returned value in main method like

```
int count = countUniqueCharacters(s);
System.out.println(count);
```

or using this one-liner

```
System.out.println(countUniqueCharacters(s));
```

---

BTW since Java 8 your code can look like

```
s.toLowerCase().chars().distinct().summaryStatistics().getCount()
```

or if you want to skip spaces you can add

```
s.toLowerCase().replace(" ","").chars().distinct().summaryStatistics().getCount()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int countUniqueCharacters(String s) {
        char [] input=s.toCharArray();
        Set<Character> charset=new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            charset.add(input[i]);
        }
        return charset.size();
    }
```